# How to design a monitor algorithm to detect a surge of traffic?

Tags: algorithm, monitoring, alarm, traffic

I am now developing a monitoring system to detect a surge of traffic for host/uri.The detailed procedure is to read the real-time nginx access log , ,compute the total traffic for each host and and report the traffic surge.

For example , for each 1 minute , if a traffic for a host is up to 1000/minute , my algorithm will find it. But ,

1. my monitoring system have many hosts to monitor at the same time
2. the activity of  hosts vary widely from each other
3. the activity of each single host varies widely over time during a day.

So , just configure a thread-hold for each host is not a good solution. Any one could give me some suggestions? What I want to achieve, is to find a auto-detect method which could alarm for a sudden/unexpected traffic surge according to the traffic statistic data of each each host for every minute and requires little pre-configuration and is more or less intelligent?

Answer (score 0):

Baron Schwartz, author of the Percona toolkit, the High Performance MySQL book, and cofounder of VividCortex recently released a free book on this subject: [Anomaly detection for monitoring](https://ruxit.com/anomaly-detection/#anomalydetection_start).

I've heard him speak at several conferences.  He's very impressive.  (Many of those talks are on YouTube.)